# Is it possible and advisable to use subthemes in Material-UI?

Tags: themes, material-ui

Frequently parts of a UI will have a contrasting color scheme from the rest of the UI.  For example, frame components of various sorts are often "reverse video" in some sense.

It would be nice if there was a way to specify a subtheme on a component, such as a navbar or a frame header, that would apply to all its children.  Is this possible and advisable?

This will conflict with a few cases (notably AppBar) that reverse colors on their own.

Failing that, FWIW, I'm using a HOC to apply styling (Typescript, not thoroughly tested):

```
import {Toolbar} from 'material-ui/Toolbar'

const reverseStyle = {
    backgroundColor: palette.frameBackground,
    color: palette.frameForeground,
}

type MetaComponent<P> = React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>

function reverse
    <P extends {style?:React.CSSProperties}>
    (Comp: MetaComponent<P>)
    : React.StatelessComponent<P>
{
    return (props:P) => {
        const { style, ...other } = props as any
        return (<Comp style={{...reverseStyle,...style}} {...other}/>
        )
    }
}
export const ReverseToolbar = reverse(Toolbar)
//...etc...
```